# I have some data in MongoDB that I need to migrate to another MongoDB, but _id is getting stored in different format

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

Legacy MongoDb is having _id in below format

[legacy mongodb id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTcfm.png)

New MongoDB is having _id in below format

```
_id: "{"$oid": "57f2773113b28328a0dabfe4"}"
```

How to make data same as legacy? like below

```
"_id": {
    "$oid": "57f2773113b28328a0dabfe2"
},
```

Source Connector Configuration:

```
{
  "name": "************************",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "MongoDbAtlasSource",
    "name": "***************",
    "kafka.auth.mode": "KAFKA_API_KEY",
    "kafka.api.key": "*******************",
    "kafka.api.secret": "*********************",
    "topic.prefix": "*****************",
    "connection.host": "*************************",
    "connection.user": "***************",
    "connection.password": "****************",
    "database": "*************",
    "collection": "*************8",
    "poll.await.time.ms": "5000",
    "poll.max.batch.size": "100",
    "pipeline": "[]",
    "copy.existing": "true",
    "copy.existing.pipeline": "[]",
    "batch.size": "0",
    "output.data.format": "JSON",
    "publish.full.document.only": "true",
    "json.output.decimal.format": "BASE64",
    "change.stream.full.document": "default",
    "output.json.format": "DefaultJson",
    "topic.separator": ".",
    "heartbeat.interval.ms": "0",
    "heartbeat.topic.name": "__mongodb_heartbeats",
    "mongo.errors.tolerance": "NONE",
    "server.api.deprecation.errors": "false",
    "server.api.strict": "false",
    "tasks.max": "1"
  }
}
```

Sink Connector Configuration:

```
{
  "name": "*********************",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "MongoDbAtlasSink",
    "name": ""*********************",",
    "input.data.format": "JSON",
    "cdc.handler": "None",
    "delete.on.null.values": "false",
    "max.batch.size": "0",
    "bulk.write.ordered": "true",
    "rate.limiting.timeout": "0",
    "rate.limiting.every.n": "0",
    "write.strategy": "DefaultWriteModelStrategy",
    "kafka.auth.mode": "KAFKA_API_KEY",
    "kafka.api.key": "*********************",
    "kafka.api.secret": "*********************",
    "topics": "*********************",
    "connection.host": "*********************",
    "connection.user": "*********************",
    "connection.password": "*********************",
    "database": "*********************",
    "collection": "*********************",
    "doc.id.strategy": "FullKeyStrategy",
    "doc.id.strategy.overwrite.existing": "false",
    "document.id.strategy.uuid.format": "string",
    "key.projection.type": "none",
    "value.projection.type": "none",
    "namespace.mapper.class": "DefaultNamespaceMapper",
    "namespace.mapper.error.if.invalid": "false",
    "server.api.deprecation.errors": "false",
    "server.api.strict": "false",
    "max.num.retries": "3",
    "retries.defer.timeout": "5000",
    "timeseries.timefield.auto.convert": "false",
    "timeseries.timefield.auto.convert.date.format": "yyyy-MM-dd[['T'][ ]][HH:mm:ss[[.][SSSSSS][SSS]][ ]VV[ ]'['VV']'][HH:mm:ss[[.][SSSSSS][SSS]][ ]X][HH:mm:ss[[.][SSSSSS][SSS]]]",
    "timeseries.timefield.auto.convert.locale.language.tag": "en",
    "timeseries.expire.after.seconds": "0",
    "ts.granularity": "None",
    "tasks.max": "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your first ID is a string, not an object. It **should** be an object, IMO. Where are your key + converter class settings?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm configuring in Confluent Cloud, but I didn't notice any converter classes there. legacy mongodb _id is of type ObjectId

Comment: Confluent Cloud shouldn't matter. Converters are required properties for connectors, even if they call it something else

Comment: Actually i didn't provide any converters. Only thing we are using is JSON, Avro

Comment: As mentioned, converters are required. If they are not in the Connector config, they are defined on the Connect worker server. But you can still set them on the connector itself. So... What values are they? Because you cannot use both json and Avro at the same time. The reason I ask is that JSONConverter will create flat strings (as you call new). And Avro will create objects (what you call legacy)... How are you consuming the data to look at the format? Can you share the command without looking in Confluent Cloud topic browser?